# How to take advantages of interfaces while using Providers?

Tags: flutter, dart, interface, flutter-change-notifier

Let's say I have 3 ChangeNotifierProviders "Auth1","Auth2","Auth3". I want all of them to implement login(),signup(),isAuthenticated().

So that I can replace one provider with another whenever I want.

```
//Interface
class IAuth {
 Future<void> signUp(String email, String password)=>throw UnimplementedError();
 Future<void> login(String email, String password) => throw UnimplementedError();
 Future<bool> isAuthenticted() => throw UnimplementedError();
 void logout() => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

I can define

> class Auth1 extends ChangeNotifier implements IAuth { ... }

> class Auth2 extends ChangeNotifier implements IAuth { ... }

> class Auth3 extends ChangeNotifier implements IAuth { ... }

But how can I provide the providers, in such a way that I can replace them without any problem in the future?

> ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Auth1())

After sometime, I may want to replace Auth1 with Auth2 and also I want to know whether this is a trivial question

Comment: Why do you want to replace providers?

Comment: Suppose let's say I have various authentication providers, one using JWT, another using some other authentication mechanism. I wanted my provider to work regardless of what authentication provider I use.

Comment: This seems like a similar problem I am facing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76403906/. Did you find any elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier using ProviderScope in RiverPod.  (RiverPod was written by the author of Provider to solve a new range of problems.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party; However; I just faced the same issue and the solution is to create an abstract class that extends ChangeNotifier and then create Provider with your implementation of the abstract class.

```
abstract class AbstractAuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
    int? _userId;
    int get userId => userId
}
    
class Auth1Provider extends ChangeNotifier implements AbstractAuthProvider {
  int? _userId;
  int get userId => userId
}

class Auth2Provider extends ChangeNotifier implements AbstractAuthProvider {
  int? _userId;
  int get userId => userId
}

class Auth3Provider extends ChangeNotifier implements AbstractAuthProvider {
  int? _userId;
  int get userId => userId
}
    
Provider<AbstractAuthProvider>(
    create: (_) => Auth1Provider(),
    child: Consumer<AbstractAuthProvider>(context, auth1Provider, child){
        final userId = Provider.of<AbstractAuthProvider>(context).userId;
        return Column(
            childrens: [
                Text(userId.toInt()) /// will print user id value from auth1 provider
                Container(
                  child: Provider<AbstractAuthProvider>(
                    create: (_) => Auth2Provider(),
                    child: Consumer<AbstractAuthProvider>(context, auth2Provider, child){
                      final userId2 = Provider.of<AbstractAuthProvider>(context).userId;
                      return Text(userId2.toInt()) // will print user id value from auth 2 provider
                      // it will always get the value of nearest provider
                    }
                  )
                )
            ]
        )
    }
)
```